# Set a Cookie by Remote server in Quasar Electron app (built)

Tags: cookies, electron, cors, quasar-framework

I have recently tried to convert my web app from SPA to a Electron app using Quasar.js framework. It's all running great, but there is problem creating a session or **setting any cookie at all by my remote server**.

I have run the app in development, where app runs on localhost and sure that worked as my back-end is localhost too. But when I build the app it is running from the "file://some/path/index.html" and backend is still "http://localhost:port".

**So I tried** setting some unsafe options for cookie as follows: `{ secure: true, httpOnly: false, path: "/", sameSite: "none" }`. I believed "sameSite" and "secure" with these values would allow setting the cookie on client, but nothing happened. I believe the HTTP should not be problem based on "(except on localhost)" on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#secure). But even though I receive  `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true Set-Cookie: cookieName=cookieVal; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None` cookie is not being set for the "file://", weird is that when I redirect to a "http://localhost" page in app. It shows the cookie there so there must be some great error in my logic of cookies. Also tried "**webSecurity: false**" option of "mainWindow.webPreferences" but no effect.

**How may I set the cookie for app running on "file://" scheme by a server running on "http://"? Or is there any other way that I'm missing to implement such a session management between app and remote server?**

Sorry if stuff I say doesn't make sense, but that's how I think it should work. Please correct me if you can, look forward to anything that could be helpful for solving the issue as I can't find any, while not knowing what to search for apparently.

Comment: Browsers reject attempts by insecure origins like `http://localhost:port` to set a `Secure` cookie. That's most likely the problem here.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks will try to get an cert to the remote server then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, indeed the cookie is now set that I added SSL to the server (origin). It's not visible in devTools but is present. Thank you very much.